# Height of recycler view item changes unexpectedly when clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment with a search view and a recycler view with which you can select one item at a time (the selected item will be highlighted). Item height may vary depending on the content being displayed. When a recycler views item is clicked, I am changing the background color of that item, and then storing the selected item to a variable for later use. However, when the item is being selected, height of it, is also changing dramatically. Its like item's detail is being collapsed or expanded unintentionally (just seems not really).

I am not very sure, but I think it has something to do with the reuse of cell. I am unable to figure out the exact issue as I just started working on android.

Here is the [link to the video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f58lgn6inni6mf1/Recycler%20View%20Issue.mov?dl=0) showing the problem, in case needed.

How can I fix this?

My adapter class is-

```
public class CodeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CodeListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Code> codes;
    private Code selectedCode;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;

    public CodeListAdapter(Code selectedCode) {
        this.selectedCode = selectedCode;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_code, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Code code = codes.get(position);
        holder.codeIdentifier.setText(code.getCodeIdentifier());

        if (code.getCodeType() == null || code.getCodeType().isEmpty()) {
            holder.codeType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.codeType.setText(code.getCodeType());
        }

        if (code.getCodeDescription() == null || code.getCodeDescription().isEmpty()) {
            holder.codeDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.codeDescription.setText(code.getCodeDescription());
        }

        if (selectedCode == code) {
            holder.itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorEmphasis);
        } else {
            holder.itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorWhite);
        }

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = holder;
        holder.itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View itemView) {
                int currentPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (currentPosition != selectedPosition) {
                    selectedCode = codes.get(currentPosition);
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                    selectedPosition = currentPosition;
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return codes.size();
    }

    public void setCodes(List<Code> codes) {
        this.codes = codes;
    }

    public Code getCode() {
        return selectedCode;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View itemLayout;
        TextView codeIdentifier;
        TextView codeType;
        TextView codeDescription;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
            codeIdentifier = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codeIdentifier);
            codeType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codeType);
            codeDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codeDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

Item's layout file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black75PercentColor"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/codeIdentifier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/codeType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/codeIdentifier" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/codeDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/codeType" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Layout file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:queryHint="@string/key_search_code" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Codes"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <mdbilling.ca.mdbilling_android.Customs.ExtendedRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/diagnosticCodeRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageHeader"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageBody"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageHeader"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Customs.ExtendedRecyclerView** here is nothing but an extension ([from this gist](https://gist.github.com/adelnizamutdinov/31c8f054d1af4588dc5c)) of recycler view which have the capability of displaying `@android:id/empty` view, whenever dataset in adapter is empty.

Did I do anything wrong or is it the way it is?

Comment: Please append the Code class code to the question. May be something goes wrong in getCodeDescription().

Comment: @ConductedClever, Thanks for your interest. My Code class is a simple java class extending from RealmObject class. getCodeDescription() method is a very simple regular getter for codeDescription property of Code class which in return gives String. Nothing fancy there. :(

Comment: @PankajDubey Im not sure about the static of viewholder class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested your code. I will share the video recorded and the source code to you. May It can help you find the issue.

MainActivity:

```
package info.androidhive.recyclerview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        prepareMovieData();
    }

    private void prepareMovieData() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("The Martian", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Up", "Animation", "2009");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Trek", "Science Fiction", "2009");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("The LEGO Movie", "Animation", "2014");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Iron Man", "Action & Adventure", "2008");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Aliens", "Science Fiction", "1986");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Chicken Run", "Animation", "2000");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Back to the Future", "Science Fiction", "1985");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Raiders of the Lost Ark", "Action & Adventure", "1981");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Goldfinger", "Action & Adventure", "1965");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2014");
        movieList.add(movie);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

The adapter:

```
package info.androidhive.recyclerview;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> moviesList;
    private Movie selectedMovie;
    private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre, desc;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
            desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
        holder.desc.setText(movie.getGenre() + movie.getGenre() + movie.getGenre() + movie.getGenre() + movie.getGenre() + movie.getGenre() + movie.getGenre());

        if (selectedMovie == movie) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorEmphasis);
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorWhite);
        }

        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = holder;
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View itemView) {
                int currentPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (currentPosition != lastSelectedPosition) {
                    selectedMovie = moviesList.get(currentPosition);
                    notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
                    lastSelectedPosition = currentPosition;
                    notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

Row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally the video:

[Video showing the code works just fine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0FIRloABflEWFNhRnBFOUJqdjA/view?usp=sharing)

TG.

// UPDATE_1 ***

The complete source code is shared in zip file format here:

[source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0FIRloABflETUt5UndQTDZBWFU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Dear @ConductedClever, I am not sure, from where to import RecyclerTouchListener? I am not getting any reference to this class with android studio's intelligence. Did I need something else?

Comment: I will share entire project with you. Wait a min.

Comment: Thanks for the precious help. I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand what your problem is, you should set your view's click listener inside the `ViewHolder` class.

Comment: Okay, do I need to do that in constructor? But then how will I get holder.getAdapterPosition() there? Can you please give me sample code?

Comment: Yes you should set it in the constructor.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, I had to make ViewHolder class not-static to get access to selectedPosition variable. Didn't work :(

Comment: Hmm...my other suggestion is that you add a bool attribute to your `Code` class (let be called isChecked), which will be the one to be checked in order to set the height/background color of the cell, instead of setting the selectedPosition every time. The click listener will toggle the value of this attribute (true/false) and change accordingly your view's background/height.

Comment: Will try that and let you know. Btw, I was looking for the cause. I have many recycler views having same problem.

Comment: This is definetely because you set your click listener inside onbindviewholder, so you are reusing a click listener which is not correct. Inside onbindviewholder you should only set values (texts/background colors etc) to views according to each element's status. I think that if you try my suggestion everything will work :). Otherwise I will try your code tomorrow and see if I can work it out.

Comment: Hmm.., that makes sense. I will try you code tomorrow. Hope that does the job. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
you don't need to call for  **int currentPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();** instead you can use the **position** from the onBindeViewHolder Method itself, for changing the background you just need to call holder.itemView.setOnCLickListner(); if you want to select deselect the itemRow then just keep a flag for that selected position as selected/ not selected.